# pre-commit Failed : an unexpected error. spawn UNKNOWN -- Jhipster project

Tags: node.js, jhipster, prettier, pre-commit

I got an error while trying to commit !

- node : v16.16.0
- generator-jhipster : 6.10.1

error :

```
$ git commit -m "message"
husky > pre-commit (node v16.16.0)
Stashing changes... [started]
Stashing changes... [skipped]
→ No partially staged files found...
Running linters... [started]
Running tasks for {,src/**/}*.{json,md,yml,ts,css,scss} [started]
prettier --write [started]
prettier --write [failed]
→ × prettier --write got an unexpected error.
spawn UNKNOWN
Running tasks for {,src/**/}*.{json,md,yml,ts,css,scss} [failed]
→ × prettier --write got an unexpected error.
spawn UNKNOWN
Running linters... [failed]
× prettier --write got an unexpected error.
spawn UNKNOWN
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

I can't figure out what is missing ! Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

[Husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/) is used by JHipster to install a g[it pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_git_hooks) that is run by git before doing a commit, if this script fails then the commit is not executed.

You can see the script, it's `.husky/pre-commit` it runs Prettier to format your code.

So you have 2 choices:

- you keep this hook and you understand why `prettier` fails by running it manually: `npm run prettier:format`
- you remove this hook, see https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=uninstall

As your project was generated your by an old version of JHipster, it would probably be a good first step to update Prettier's version and its plugins in `package.json` and run `npm install`.

**Personal opinion**

I think it's a bad idea to keep this hook because it's not documented and because I think it's your IDE's job to format your code and overtime Prettier can fail because you are now using a newer version of Java or Typescript with new syntax. To me, it creates technical debt for future maintainers of your project.

Comment: i said it's clair, when the solution works then i mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud, i am sorry 